# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED easyphp

Tags: easyphp

I have EasyPHP version 17 installed in Windows 7 pro OS .I have no access to the dashboard "index.php" of the program (err_connection_refused). 
I have change the port of skype (port 80) but the problem still exist. 
I Need to know what happened or what can i do. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and I found a workaround for this. Just reinstall easyPHP and then try. It will work.